# Two query conditions are different, one executes the index and the other does not. I want to know why

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two almost identical sql statements. Since their query conditions are different, one executes the index and the other does not. I want to know why.

```
SELECT 
    f.name AS "省", e.name AS "市", d.name AS "区", 
    t.name AS "街道", c.name AS "居委会"
FROM 
    DICT_REGION_TOWNSHIP t
JOIN 
    DICT_REGION_NEIGHBOR_COMMITTEE c ON t.code = c.parent_code
JOIN 
    DICT_REGION_COUNTY d ON t.parent_code = d.code
JOIN 
    DICT_REGION_CITY e ON d.parent_code = e.code
JOIN 
    DICT_REGION f ON e.parent_code = f.code
WHERE 
    f.code = '110000000000'

SELECT 
    f.name AS "省", e.name AS "市", d.name AS "区", 
    t.name AS "街道", c.name AS "居委会"
FROM 
    DICT_REGION_TOWNSHIP t
JOIN 
    DICT_REGION_NEIGHBOR_COMMITTEE c ON t.code = c.parent_code
JOIN 
    DICT_REGION_COUNTY d ON t.parent_code = d.code
JOIN 
    DICT_REGION_CITY e ON d.parent_code = e.code
JOIN 
    DICT_REGION f ON e.parent_code = f.code
WHERE 
    c.code = '620524108210'
```

The code column in these five tables has an index. I want to know why one of these two statements has an index and the other does not.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekX9h.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XcDr.png)

Answer (score 4):

The decision to use indexes, what join order, what join method, what transformations, etc... are all made by the optimizer at parse time based on your SQL and its knowledge of the data (statistics). There is a massive difference between applying a predicate to one table (`DICT_REGION_NEIGHBOR_COMMITTEE`) vs. applying a predicate to a totally different table (`DICT_REGION`). You cannot expect the plans to be anything alike. The join order would be totally different, and the cardinality estimates vastly different as well.

As `DICT_REGION` appears to be the highest-level entity (fewest distinct values), starting with a region can easily influence the optimizer to use hash or merge joins rather than nested loops + indexes because it believes, and it may be correct, that that will be faster than a nested loops approach. A single region will mean a *lot* of neighborhood committees, too many to use an index with. But a single neighborhood committee will only join to *one* township, county, city and region, making nested loops + index access ideal.

Your first query plan however looks particularly concerning because of the cartesian joins. Those are usually (not always) indicative a problem. I suspect your statistics are not gathered on all your tables. Gather stats and try again. I would fully expect hash joins on that first query but they should go in order (f -> e -> d -> t -> c). If Oracle thinks one of them is empty it very well might use a different order and employ a cartesian join (because the join column needed isn't yet available in the join order chosen). If it's correct about the table being empty, then it's actually correct about its plan, even a cartesian join.

No plan is "wrong" by itself. There are lots of situations were index use is the worst thing, and avoiding it the best thing (and other situations were it's the opposite). Only when considered against the actual data we know to be in the tables can we determine that a plan is wrong (assuming we understand how to read a plan and have a basic understanding of what Oracle would be doing internally at each step).

Even if the plan *is* wrong (there's a better one available) it doesn't warrant attention unless it's *badly* wrong. Which leads to the corollary that no plan should concern us unless we are actually experiencing poor performance. Only then do we compare the plan with our knowledge of the data to find where Oracle might be making a mistake. Fixing it might involve gathering stats, adding hints, or rewriting the query.